# Issue with passing find command via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh, solaris

I am trying to read content on specific files. I have multiple hosts where these files are located. I am passing the commands below during ssh so that it can run and get the output.

1. When using the command below I get the specified errors. (its sshed to host but nothing happens)

   ```
   $ ssh host "more $(find /my/path -name "test*")"
   find: 0652-010 The starting directory is not valid.
   ```
2. When using exec its not working, (its sshed to host but nothing happens)

   ```
   $ ssh host "find /my/path -name "test*" -exec more {} \;"`
   ```
3. When using xargs it is working as expected

   ```
   $ ssh host "find /my/path -name "test*" | xargs more"
   ```

**Can someone explain why method 1 & 2 are not working?**

Please note that if I directly run command on remote host every method is working.
for example all commands below are working as expected in remote host.

```
more $(find /my/path -name "test*")

find /my/path -name "test*" -exec more {} \;

find /my/path -name "test*" | xargs more
```

Answer (score 7):

For (1) the `"... $(command substitution)"` inside the "double-quote string" is being done by your **local** bash shell, you'll need to escape it so that that it seen & expanded until the command reaches the remote box:

```
ssh host "more \$(find /my/path -name 'test*')"
```

OR, because 'single quotes' don't expand `$()`:

```
ssh host 'more $(find /my/path -name "test*")'
```

**NOTE A** - The above solutions are also careful to ensure that `test*` is still quoted (single or double it doesn't matter) when reaches the remote box, because it's important that `find` sees the exact string `test*`, not what it *might* glob/`*`/expand into IF there happened to be file names starting with test in the remote home dir.

For (2) similarly, you need to escape the `\` so it is passed correctly to the remote box:

```
ssh host "find /my/path -name 'test*' -exec more {} \\;"
```

OR, because 'single quotes' don't -escape:

```
ssh host 'find /my/path -name "test*" -exec more {} \;'
```

For (3) be careful about **NOTE A**.  When your (3) command reaches the remote host `test*` is NOT quoted. Adding another layer or escaping of quotes will make it safer:

```
ssh host "find /my/path -name \"test*\" | xargs more"
```

OR

```
ssh host "find /my/path -name 'test*' | xargs more"
```

**Caveat B** - Programs like `more` interact with your terminal/tty so you might need to force the remote sshd to allocate one with `ssh -t host ...`

**Caveat C** - All of the above assumes that your user's shell on the remote box is a "normal"/Bourne -type of shell (bash, dash, ash, sh, zsh).  If remote user account has changed their login shell to something weird (tcsh, fish, ...) you would need to add *another* layer of quote-escaping to and invoke your commands in particular shell (bash f/ex):  `ssh host "/bin/bash -c \"more \\\$(find /my/path -name 'test*')\""`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. Especially take a look at the double quotes: you enclose the set of double quotes around the `test*` *inside* another set of double quotes. How should a shell understand that? Instead you have to "escape" (so protect) the inner quotes. And you should use the `more` (or `less`) command *locally* since you want to limit to the local terminal length:

This version of your first attempt works as expected:

```
ssh host "find /my/path -name \"test*\"" | more
```

Comment: I am trying to find file and read that using more. Method 3 also has inner quotes but that one works then why method 1 does not work? As you mentioned I tried by escaping inner quotes too but its not working.

Comment: Ah, this is something different... You see find returns a list of files, not the file(s) content... You can use `xargs` to further process (use) such a list of files, but not with `more` (`less`) on the _server_ side, since you do not have a terminal there. The command cannot decide about the length of your screen, so where to halt output. Instead it will flush the whole file, just like a `cat` would do. Which again means you can pipe that output into a _local_ command: `ssh host "find /my/path -name \"test*\" | xargs cat" | more`...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quoting.

In the first case you run `find` *locally* . Try `ssh host "echo $(hostname)"`. The second method runs `more` on suitable *each file* separately.

Answer (score 0):

You should do as below:

ssh host "ksh -c 'find /my/path -name \"test*\" -exec more {} \;'"`

When use "-c" as an option ksh reads the command as a string and run it directly